# Mobile Push, AMP Scripting a dynamic message based on device language

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, language, mobilepush

Attempting to deploy a Mobile Push message from SFMC where the message dynamically updates based on the subscriber's Device Language attribute.

How do I retrieve the 'Mobile Push Demographics' attributes (specifically device language, and their attribute values) via AMP Scripting?  Don't know which existing DE to point the LookUp function to.  Do I need to define a custom DE for this uses case?

Trying to collect & set the subscriber's device language:

`%%[VAR @devicelang]%%
%%[SET @devicelang = Lookup("MobilePush Demographics", "Device Language")]%%
The Device Language is '%%= v(@devicelang) =%%'`

Comment: If `devicelang` is your `attribute` then try `%%devicelang%%`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work...

```
%%=Lookup("_PushAddressExtension", "DeviceLanguage", "DeviceId", DeviceID)=%%
```